# Invalid Package: This Package is not available

Tags: managed-package

We have manage package created for our customer. Its not on app exchange. This package works fine on many customer orgs and number of dev orgs. There is this new customer who gets error when he tries to install our package. [image]

I have following quetions?

1) What could be the possible reason of this error.
2) How to tackle this error(with SF support)

The interesting thing is its working on all other of orgs except one.

This package does not required any special features like multi currency and all.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when you upload new package many time it take some time to go live thus it gives error that the package is not yet available.

Comment: Nope this package is online since 2013 and working fine for many other customers. it also works on new Dev orgs.

Comment: Can you try to install again this package.?

Comment: Yes, did that multiple times but same result.